# Filter Data by multiple keywords

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I wrote a Python script to filter rows from a csv file by keyword. Here is my main-search-function:

```
search_keywords= 'CVE-2017-XX|OpenSSL|XYZ'    
df_rest = pd.DataFrame(df_rest[df_rest[[0,1,2,3,4,5]].apply(lambda r: r.str.contains(search_keywords, case=False).any(), axis=1)])
```

My question is how can I filter only the rows which consists 2 or 3 keywords?

Example: `ID, NAME, String1 String2 String3, COMMENT`

Filter by keyword: `String1, String3`

I want to filter the row only if both keywords are matched.

Comment: Are you searching a CSV or a dataframe?

Comment: can you edit your question, show your df.  post your df and desired output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can create for each keyword separate mask and then combine them with chaining by `&` - for at least one `True` per row use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df_rest = pd.DataFrame({0:['OpenSSL XYZ dd','dd OpenSSL','g OpenSSL'],
                   1:['CVE-2017-XX OpenSSL dd','dd OpenSSL','g XYZ'],
                   2:['OpenSSL  t','dd XYZ','g CVE-2017-XX XYZ OpenSSL']})


cols = [0,1,2]
m1 = df_rest[cols].apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('OpenSSL', case=False))
print (m1)
      0      1      2
0  True   True   True
1  True   True  False
2  True  False   True

m2 = df_rest[cols].apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('XYZ', case=False))
print (m2)
       0      1      2
0   True  False  False
1  False  False   True
2  False   True   True

m3 = df_rest[cols].apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('CVE-2017-XX', case=False))
print (m3)
       0      1      2
0  False   True  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False   True
```

---

```
print (m1 & m2)
       0      1      2
0   True  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False   True

print ((m1 & m2).any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool

df = df_rest[(m1 & m2).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
                0                       1                          2
0  OpenSSL XYZ dd  CVE-2017-XX OpenSSL dd                 OpenSSL  t
2       g OpenSSL                   g XYZ  g CVE-2017-XX XYZ OpenSSL
```

EDIT:

Is possible some keywords are interpreted as regex. For avoid it use `regex=
False`:

```
df_rest = pd.DataFrame({0:['XYZ dd','dd OpenSSL 0.9.4','g 0.9.4'],
                   1:['0.9.4 OpenSSL dd','dd 0.9','g XYZ'],
                   2:['OpenSSL  t','dd XYZ','OpenSSL 0.9.7']})

print (df_rest)
                  0                 1              2
0            XYZ dd  0.9.4 OpenSSL dd     OpenSSL  t
1  dd OpenSSL 0.9.4            dd 0.9         dd XYZ
2           g 0.9.4             g XYZ  OpenSSL 0.9.7

cols = [0,1,2]
m = df_rest[cols].apply(lambda r: (r.str.contains('0.9.4', case=False, regex=False) & 
                                   r.str.contains('OpenSSL', case=False, regex=False)))

df = df_rest[m.any(axis=1)]                         
print (df)
                  0                 1           2
0            XYZ dd  0.9.4 OpenSSL dd  OpenSSL  t
1  dd OpenSSL 0.9.4            dd 0.9      dd XYZ
```

EDIT1:

```
df_rest = pd.DataFrame({0:['XYZ dd','dd OpenSSL 0.9.1','g 0.9.4'],
                   1:['0.9.2 OpenSSL dd','dd 0.9','g XYZ'],
                   2:['OpenSSL  t','dd XYZ','OpenSSL 0.9.1']})

print (df_rest)

df = pd.read_csv('keywords.txt', names=('a','b'))
print (df)
         a      b
0  OpenSSL  0.9.1
1  OpenSSL  0.9.2
2  OpenSSL  0.9.4

cols = [0,1,2]
for i, x in df.iterrows():
    m = df_rest[cols].apply(lambda r: (r.str.contains(x['a'], case=False, regex=False) & 
                                       r.str.contains(x['b'], case=False, regex=False)))

    df = df_rest[m.any(axis=1)] 
    f = '{0[0]}_{0[1]}.txt'.format((x['a'], x['b']))
    df.to_csv(f, index=False, header=False)
```

EDIT2:

```
dfs = []
for i, x in dfkey.iterrows(): 

    cols = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    m = df_rest[cols].apply(lambda r: (r.str.contains(x['a'], case=False, regex=False) & 
                                          r.str.contains(x['b'], case=False, regex=False)))

    df_rest = df_rest[m.any(axis=1)] 

    dfs.append(df_rest)
pd.concat(dfs).to_csv('text.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: As always very fast!

Comment: Sure I was thinking of the same solution so it is good to confirm it is right

Comment: I am working with a keyword.txt file. This is my problem. I also tryed this: df_rest = pd.DataFrame(df_rest[df_rest[[0,1,2,3,4,5]].apply(lambda r: (r.str.contains('OpenSSL', case=False).any()) and (r.str.contains('0.9.4', case=False).any()), axis=1)]) but it filter also 0.9 instead of 0.9.4

Comment: No it split's my string because of the dot: 0.9.4

Comment: Code: df_rest = pd.DataFrame(df_rest[df_rest[[0,1,2,3,4,5]].apply(lambda r: (r.str.contains('OpenSSL', case=False).any()) and (r.str.contains('0.9.4 ', case=False).any()), axis=1)]) -> Result 
->OpenSSL 0.9.4 and OpenSSH 
->The SSL/TLS server implementation in OpenSSL 0.9.7

Comment: It works with normal strings like "OpenSSL" & "FreeBSD" but not with version numbers with more then one dot.

Comment: No, not 0.9, only 0.9.7, 0.9.1, etc.

Comment: I set: (r.str.contains('0.9.4', case=False, regex=False) and it works :)

Now how can I transform for example two strings "String1, VersionNumber" in df_rest[df_rest[[0,1,2,3,4,5]].apply(lambda r: (r.str.contains('String1, case=False) & r.str.contains('VersionNumber', case=False))).any(axis=1)]

Comment: Yes, but I want to add my data to a file like keywords.txt. 

->String1
-> String1, VersionNumber

Somthing like "if (',') then replace it by and str.contains (...)"

Comment: Do you want save output to `txt` ? Then use `df.to_csv('keywords.txt')` - there is no problem it is `txt`, no `csv`

Comment: No. I want to read the keywords from a file. This is simple. 

instead of this df_rest = pd.DataFrame(df_rest[df_rest[[0,1,2,3,4,5]].apply(lambda r: (r.str.contains('OpenSSL', case=False, regex=False).any()) and (r.str.contains('0.9.7', case=False, regex=False).any()), axis=1)])

I need something like #df_rest = pd.DataFrame(df_rest[df_rest[[0,1,2,3,4,5]].apply(lambda r: (r.str.contains(''OpenSSL'&'0.9.7', case=False, regex=False).any()), axis=1)])

Comment: What is format of file? Echa row contains 2 keywords separated by comma? Or different?

Comment: Unfortunately `OpenSSL'&'0.9.7` does not exist.

Comment: A simple keyword.txt file. Keywords can be separated by comma or something like that.

Comment: OK, so [link to file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ejsbsi0xf0z8oto/keywords.txt?dl=0) should be? And output is for each row separate file with filtered data, right?

Comment: Yes. File can by String, Vers or online string.

Comment: My file looks like yours.

Comment: Super, please check solution.

Comment: My file which I want to filter is very large (80 MB). 

df = pd.read_csv(csv_cvefile, delimiter=',',  header=None,engine='python',usecols=range(0, 6), error_bad_lines=False)

df_rest = pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[9:])
dff = pd.read_csv('keywords.txt', names=('a','b'))
print (dff)
for i, x in dff.iterrows():
    df_rest = pd.DataFrame(df_rest[df_rest[[0,1,2,3,4,5]].apply(lambda r: (r.str.contains(x['a'], case=False, regex=False) & r.str.contains(x['b'], case=False, regex=False)), axis=1)])

I get errors from merging after that

Comment: What happend if I use only 'a' and 'b' is NaN?

Comment: Then it failed, the best is replace NaN like `df = pd.read_csv('keywords.txt', names=('a','b')).fillna('')`

Comment: It works with "String1, 0.9.4". But it doesn't work only with "String1". I get the error "No columns to parse from file". And if I use to rows with a second String and versionnumber it doesn't work too ... because merging is not working.

Comment: It is some data problme, really hard help if I dont see your real data ... :(

Comment: Other possibility could be to to open the file and extract the first column. Then to append the elements elements rowwise in the Form "String1|String2" and repait this with second column.

Comment: @TigerClaw - I think it is not what you need, because `String1|String2` is `String1` `OR` `String2` and you want ``String1` `AND` `String2` `

Comment: There is a possibility fpr AND operation with regex: /(OpenSSL)(0.9.4)/

But I have to use ".extract" or something like that in my code: df_rest = pd.DataFrame(df_rest[df_rest[[0,1,2,3,4,5]].apply(lambda r: (r.str.contains(search_keywords, case=False, regex=True).any()), axis=1)])
But donÄ' know how to implement

Comment: Unfortunately not, AND is not possible in regex.

Comment: If I have more then one row in my keyword.txt I get only the result for the last row: for i, x in dfkey.iterrows():
   #df_rest = df_rest[[cols]].apply(lambda r: (r.str.contains(x[0], case=False, regex=False).any() and (r.str.contains(x[1], case=False, regex=False).any())), axis=1)
    df_rest = (df_rest[df_rest[[0,1,2,3,4,5]].apply(lambda r: (r.str.contains(x[0], case=False, regex=True).any()) and (r.str.contains(x[1], case=False, regex=True).any()), axis=1)])
    df_rest.to_csv('text.csv', index=False, header=False)
    print (df_rest)

Comment: You overwrite your output file - need for each combunation separate file, see my last paragraph. I use `f` what is generated `df.to_csv(f, index=False, header=False)`

Comment: So I have to save first my data and open the file again to add new columns or merge the file with old version? 

The for-loop overwrites my file. It doesn't append the rows(python 3)

Comment: Ceck last edit. Btw, if still some problem, the best is accept this solution and create new question. thank you.

Comment: I did it like this: 
df_rest = pd.DataFrame(df_rest[df_rest[[0,1,2,3,4,5]].apply(lambda r: (r.str.contains(x[0], case=False, regex=True).any()) and (r.str.contains(x[1], case=False, regex=True).any()), axis=1)])
for i, x in dfkey.iterrows():       
    if (i == 0):
        
         df = pd.concat([df_header, df_rest], axis=0)
        df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
        df.to_csv(csv_tempfile, index=True, header=None)
           
    if (i >= 1):
        df.to_csv(csv_tempfile, mode='a', header=False)

Comment: Your solution works only with first one or two rows in keyword.txt data

Comment: Maybe problem is no match for another data, please check `#print (df_rest)` by uncommneting if dataframe has no empty for some keywords rows.

Comment: It show's me only the matched data from first row of keywords.txt.

Comment: I see your problem - use bad code with double any. need last paragraph. Cannot use double any, only once. I test it with sample data (`[0,1,2]` instead `[0,1,2,3,4,5]`) and it working perfectly. So some problem with your data if it return only one row.

Comment: OK, I have one idea. Please send me your data, your code and I can check it. Because it seems some doata related problem and it is not possible solve without them. My email is in my profile.

Comment: I send you a mail a few days ago ;)

Comment: I send it again

Comment: I dont see it, mail was sent?

Comment: I check it and nothing. Whats your email?

Comment: thanks, I see it. But no data. I need your real data, because data problem.

Comment: send it as data

Comment: I find problem, I send you email